# Powershell equivalent to sponge in moreutils?

Tags: powershell

There's a GNU program called *sponge* that soaks up input before writing to a file so you can do something like this: `cat myFile | grep "myFilter" | sponge myFile`

Is there a powershell equivalent, so I can work on a file in place, without having to pipe to a temporary file?

Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide example input and then the expected output as a result of sponge.

Comment: @Scott: It just buffers everything until the input stops, then writes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Powershell, judicious use of parentheses will force an operation to completely finish before passing data to the next command in the pipeline. The default for piping `Get-Content` is to pipe line by line to the next command, but with parentheses it must form a complete data set (e.g., load all lines) before continuing:

```
(Get-Content myFile) | Select-String 'MyFilter' | Set-Content myFile
```

An alternative that may use less memory (I have not benchmarked it) is to only force the results of `Select-String` to complete before continuing:

```
(Get-Content myFile | Select-String 'MyFilter') | Set-Content myFile
```

You could also assign things to a variable as an additional step. Any technique will load the contents into the Powershell session's memory, so be careful with big files.

*Addendum:* `Select-String` returns `MatchInfo` objects. Using `Out-File` adds pesky extra blank lines due to the way it tries to format the results as a string, but `Set-Content` correctly converts each object to its own string as it writes, producing better output. Being that you're coming from *nix and are used to everything returning strings (whereas Powershell returns objects), one way to force string output is to pipe them through a `foreach` that converts them:

```
(Get-Content myFile | Select-String 'MyFilter' | foreach { $_.tostring() }) | Set-Content myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
(Get-content myfile) | where {$_ -match "regular-expression"} | Set-content myfile
```

or

```
${full-path-file-name-of-myfile} | where {$_ -match "regular-expression"} | add-content Anotherfile
```

more easier to keep in mind

Answer (score 1):

two other ways come to mind - they are both the same really just one is a function the other is on the command line. (I don't know sponge on unix so I can't say for certain they mimic it).

here's the first on the command line

```
Get-Content .\temp.txt | 
    Select-String "grep" | 
    foreach-object -begin { [array] $out  = @()} -process { $out = $out + ($_.tostring())} -end {write-output $out}
```

and the second is two create a function to do it

```
function sponge {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [string]$Output
    )
    Begin {
        [array] $out = @()
    }
    Process {
        $out = $out + $Output
    }
    End {
        Write-Output $Out
    }
}


Get-Content .\temp2.txt | Select-String "grep" | sponge
```

HTH,
Matt