# How to update some values in a json file and save changes in the same file by jq

Tags: json, git, shell, file, jq

I have the following json file :

```
{
  "src": "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myrepos/project",
  "version": "master",
  "archetype_version": "master",
  "roles": [
    {
      "src": "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myrepos/project",
      "version": "master"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change the version from master to another one, so I do the following command:

```
 cat file.json | jq '.roles[0].version = "new"' | jq '.version = "new"' | jq '.archetype_version = "new"' > file2.json
```

How to save the changes to `file.json` not to `file2.json` because I'll need to use the same file later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is:

```
..file1.json|..|..|.. >file2.json && mv file2.json file1.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sponge` in "moreutils" (https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).  See the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) for further details and options.

By the way, you can compress your pipeline so that there is just one invocation of jq and no invocation of `cat`:

```
< file.json jq '
.roles[0].version = "new"
| .version = "new"
| .archetype_version = "new"' | sponge file.json
```

Of course overwriting the input file without first backing it up generally carries some risk, so in many ways a two-step process such as the following is best:

```
mv file.json file.tmp && < file.tmp jq .... > file.json
```

Comment: Will this work from a Windows 10 OS?

Comment: @Neo: if you do not have access to `sponge`, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604852/powershell-equivalent-to-sponge-in-moreutils

Comment: So no need for JQ to parse out the JSON I need?