# find and replace a value in a json file using bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have several `.json` files similar to this.

```
{
    "AcquisitionNumber": 1,
    "TotalReadoutTime": 0.035,
    "IntendedFor": "func/sub-02_task-rest_run-01_bold.nii.gz"
}
```

I want to change the sub number in the "IntendedFor" line using a bash variable, looping over different subs.For example if sub is 03:

```
sub=03
echo $sub
03
```

How can I change the value of `sub-02` to `sub-03` using this bash variable?

Comment: Use the JSON parser `jq`

Comment: A huge list of alternatives to jq here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011455/2440

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
jq --arg sub "$sub" '.IntendedFor |= sub("(?<=sub-)[^_]+"; $sub)' file
```

See [this online example](https://jqplay.org/s/_2xqFraagF)

Note that your `jq` binary must be compiled with regex support in order to use `sub` function.

And, you can implement inline editing using a for loop and temporary files:

```
sub=03

for jsonfile in *.json; do
    tempfile=$(mktemp -u)
    jq --arg sub "$sub" '.IntendedFor|=sub("(?<=sub-)[^_]+";$sub)' "$jsonfile" > "$tempfile"
    mv "$tempfile" "$jsonfile"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With jq and bash:

```
value=$(jq -r '.IntendedFor' file)
new_value="${value/sub-02/sub-03}"
jq --arg new "$new_value" '.IntendedFor |= $new' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "AcquisitionNumber": 1,
  "TotalReadoutTime": 0.035,
  "IntendedFor": "func/sub-03_task-rest_run-01_bold.nii.gz"
}
```

Comment: you can use jq's `--arg` option to pass shell variables to jq

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easier.

Comment: This does not change the original file but outputs the result to the terminal, right?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sponge` (part of `moreutils`):

```
for f in *.json; do
  jq --arg sub "$sub" '.IntendedFor |= sub("/sub-[^_]+";"/sub-"+$sub)' "$f" | sponge "$f"
done
```

In any case, a simple regex suffices.

## sponge for Windows

See:

- [Powershell equivalent to sponge in moreutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604852/powershell-equivalent-to-sponge-in-moreutils)
- https://github.com/zetamatta/sponge

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, but there is a bash-solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
fromstring="sub-02"
tostring="sub-03"

while read line; do
    case "$line" in
    (*IntendedFor*) echo $(line/$fromstring/$tostring) ;;
    (*)  echo $line ;;
    esac
 done < JSONfile
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your use of `cat` is a *UUOc` (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`)*. Unless you are concatenating files, if you find yourself doing `cat somethingelse`, then it is probably a UUOc. Here using *redirection*, e.g. `while read line; do ... done <jsonfile` is the proper way of feeding the `while` loop. I suspect the ding comes from the fact that parsing json or xml in bash is simply unwise, there is *zero* format validation. That is why we have tools like `jq` and `xmlstartlet`.

Comment: As I said, "There are better ways of doing this". But I thought it to be a nice puzzle for doing it in bash only. I removed the `cat` from the answer, which makes it work completely in `bash`, without external programs.

Comment: should this have the syntax `${variable//pattern/replacement}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13043344/3208553