# Add a new key/value to every object in json array in file with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file like below. I want to add "stable": "yes" to every object in this file with jq. How can i do this?

```
 [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Blue"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Red"
    }
 ]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
 [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Blue",
        "stable": "yes"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Red",
        "stable": "yes"
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` and `+` will do this:

```
$ jq 'map(. + {stable: "yes"})' tmp.json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Blue",
    "stable": "yes"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Red",
    "stable": "yes"
  }
]
```

Since the input is an array, the `.` refers to each object in that array, to which we add another object.

Note this will also override any existing `stable` key in each object.

Comment: What if it is like this { "data": [  {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Blue"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Red"
    }]}

Comment: Modify the filter to update the `data` key of the top-level object: `.data |= map(...)`. The `|=` operator pipes the left-hand side through the right-hand side, updating the original input in the process.

Comment: It just outputs it to the console but it doesn't write it to the file?

Comment: @somethingyouwant `jq` won't edit the file in place; you'll need to redirect to a second file and then replace the original.

Comment: ... or use `sponge` (or equivalent -- see especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604852/powershell-equivalent-to-sponge-in-moreutils)