# How to permanently add data to json file using jq command

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, jq, amazon-ecs

Below is my taskdef.json file

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "container_name",
            "image": "",
            "essential": true,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/taskdef",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
         }
     ]
  }
```

I'm using an environment variable to append to this file

```
export IMAGE=########.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/container-repo:latest
```

I've ran the following command to input the image under containerDefinitions and the output shows it in there but it does not get appended permanently to the taskdef.json file.

```
jq ".containerDefinitions[].image=\"$IMAGE\"" taskdef.json
```

I've also tried the following command to add the output to a new file but I have multiple json data injections so this way doesn't work.

```
jq ".containerDefinitions[].image=\"$IMAGE\"" taskdef.json > taskdef2.json
```

Is there anyway to inject an input permanently into the json file using the jq command which would be equivalent to sed -i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq does not have a command-line option like sed's `-i`.  One way to avoid having to fiddle with a temporary file is to use `sponge` (part of the `moreutils` collection) if it is available in your computing environment:

```
jq .... taskdef.json | sponge taskdef.json
```

(Homebrew users can install `sponge` via: `brew install sponge`)

For a PowerShell alternative to `sponge`, see [Powershell equivalent to sponge in moreutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604852/powershell-equivalent-to-sponge-in-moreutils)